# Add shortkey to show desktop

Tags: debian, xfce

What is the command to use when adding a shortcut to minimize all / show desktop?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under Settings -> Window Manager -> Keyboard -> Show Desktop

Application shortcuts are just that: shortcuts to **launch** applications.

Comment: There is not "Window Manager" in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

As default this shortcut is disabled. You can set the shortcut by going to:

Settings | Keyboard | Keyboard Shortcuts | View and Customize Shortcuts | Hide all normal windows

Debian 12, Gnome Version 43.9